# Python flask-restful reqparser json with list of json

Tags: python, json, unicode

```
{
 "Products":[
            {
              "Product_id":"123"
            },
            {
              "Product_id":"124"
            }
            ]
}
```

now how to access the product_ids like i need to get 123,124
Pls help. I am getting in unicode moreover from client

Answer (score 0):

```
df = {
    "Products": [
        {
            "Product_id": "123"
        },
        {
            "Product_id": "124"
        }
    ]
}

for i in df['Products']:
    for key, value in i.items():
        print('df:', value)
```

output:

```
df: 123
df: 124
```

Comment: @@nihal i m getting in unicode from client. i m unable to do that